# using DTD and XML to create bank db

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dtd

I would like to write an XML file for the following data (represented in tables):

```
Account table:
account-number    balance
   100             1000
   719             9000
   715            -3000
   600              100


Costumers table:
account-number     street    city    id
  100               ...       ...    ...
  719               ...      ...     ...
  715               ...       ...     ...
  715               ...      ....      ...
  600              ...        ...      ...
```

Since this is my first time writing in XML, im abit confused about the DTD file.
This is what I wrote:

```
<!ELEMENT bank (costumer)*>
<!ELEMENT costumer (account, street, city, id)>
<!ELEMENT account (account-number, balance)>
<!ELEMENT account-number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT balance (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST balance currency CDATA #FIXED "usd">
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
```

Does this form truly serves my intentions, or I do I have any mistakes?
Do you have anything to add/change in my code, so it best fits to describe those tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have everything covered, but only you can determine whether it fits your needs or not.

Just a couple of minor suggestions.

- Use an attribute for `id` instead of an element. That way you can be sure that it's unique and you can reference it if you need to: `<!ATTLIST costumer id ID #REQUIRED>`. You could do the same for account number too.
- Wrap `street` and `city` in an `address` element. That will make it easier to expand in the future without cluttering the model of `costumer`.

Comment: @Jjang - That is very true. ID's can't start with numbers so you'll either have to add a prefix to your id's or use CDATA (or leave it an element like you have it).

Comment: hmm, but in the costumers table, I can have 2 entries (costumers) with the same ID, while in the account table, I cannot. (so should it be an ID or not??)
p.s I decided to add a letter to the beggining of the ID :D